# Store unique values in an array then print them in another sheet

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am working on a project that involves finding a particular column in a spreadsheet, then storing only unique values in that column into an array and then printing that array on another sheet. My code is erroring out due to both a type mismatch and a with block not being set, but I can't seem to figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Find_Distincts_Policies()

Dim aCell As Range, rng As Range
Dim varIn As Variant, varUnique As Variant, element As Variant
Dim isUnique As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim colName As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim iInCol As Long, iInRow As Long, iUnique As Long, nUnique As Long, LastRow As Long

Set wkb = ThisWorkbook

Set ws = wkb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

With ws
Set aCell = .Range("A1:ZZ4").Find(what:="Unique Number", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    colName = Split(.Cells(, aCell).Address, "$")(1)
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = .Range(colName & "2:" & colName & LastRow)
varIn = rng.Value

ReDim varUnique(1 To UBound(varIn, 1) * UBound(varIn, 2))

nUnique = 0
For iInRow = LBound(varIn, 1) To UBound(varIn, 1)
    For iInCol = LBound(varIn, 2) To UBound(varIn, 2)

        isUnique = True
        For iUnique = 1 To nUnique
            If varIn(iInRow, iInCol) = varUnique(iUnique) Then
                isUnique = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next iUnique

        If isUnique = True Then
            nUnique = nUnique + 1
            varUnique(nUnique) = varIn(iInRow, iInCol)
        End If

    Next iInCol
Next iInRow
ReDim Preserve varUnique(1 To nUnique)
MsgBox varUnique
Else: Exit Sub
End If
End With

With wkb
.Worksheets.Add.Name = "Unique values"
ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = varIn
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Try using a Dictionary (it's available in the Microsoft Scripting Runtime reference) for finding unique values, you'll find it a lot easier to work with.

Comment: You might also consider VBA's`Range.RemoveDuplicates` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx

Comment: Putting aside other better means of achieving your goal, the cause of the `Type Mismatch` error is `colName = Split(.Cells(, aCell).Address, "$")(1)` ... so many thing wrong there, but really you want the column _number_. What you want is `colName = aCell.Column` and `Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, colName), .Cells(LastRow, colName))`  (you've already `Dim`'ed `colName as Long` so that's ok)